# PostgreSQL encoding issue while executing query from command line

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters, psql

I am trying to execute an SQL query which is stored in the file. I am using following command to execute:

```
psql -d DB_NAME -a -f QUERY_NAME.sql
```

I have some non English text in the SQL file like - સુરત

When the query is executed the text in the database looks like - Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¤

How do I execute the query from **command line** so that it runs correctly?

Comment: what os and client do you use?

Comment: Related: [PostgreSQL: encoding problems on Windows when using psql command line utility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952893/postgresql-encoding-problems-on-windows-when-using-psql-command-line-utility).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the [**`client_encoding`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CLIENT-ENCODING) matches the encoding of your file. Check your system locale. Then use a matching command line argument for psql. [Quoting the manual here:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-CONNECTING)

> If at least one of standard input or standard output are a terminal,
>   then psql sets the client encoding to "auto", which will detect the
>   appropriate client encoding from the locale settings (LC_CTYPE
>   environment variable on Unix systems). If this doesn't work out as
>   expected, the client encoding can be overridden using the environment
>   variable PGCLIENTENCODING.

Example for a Linux shell:

```
env PGCLIENTENCODING='WIN1258' psql DB_NAME -a -f QUERY_NAME.sql
```

[List of available encodings in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/multibyte.html#MULTIBYTE-CHARSET-SUPPORTED)