# PostgreSQL: encoding problems on Windows when using psql command line utility

Tags: sql, postgresql, command-line, character-encoding, psql

I'm working in a centralized monitoring system on Windows 2008 R2, I have installed a PostgreSQL 9.3 to use **psql** from the command line.

When I try to access to some remote Postgres (an 8.4 in my principal case) I have an error with the encoding:

command:

```
psql.exe -h 192.168.114.12 -p 5432 -d db_seros_transaccion -U postgres -f script.sql
```

error:

```
psql: FATAL:  la conversión entre WIN1252 y LATIN1 no está soportada
```

I try adding the sentence

```
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
```

in my script but the problem persist (and with other encodings too, like LATIN1 & WIN1252).

After googling it I found people that update some rows in the server to make the connection, and this is a problem to me.

Can anyone help me to make a connection using *psql* without an update? Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pgsql.bugs/Vp9HJzXY48M), i.e. running `chcp 65001` before `psql`?

Comment: Yes, after make the question, try with chcp 65001, 437, 1252 to test. not work. now I trying to use sqlrun throw an odbc (in a minutes the results ;P)

Comment: The 8.4 is on Linux, right?

Comment: In addition to `chcp 65001` to set a unicode codepage you may also need to tell `psql` it's in a unicode terminal during startup. You can't `SET client_encoding` later, because you need an already-working connection for that. Try also running `SET PGCLIENTENCODING=utf-8` (after the `chcp 65001`) before starting `psql` and report back on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot **Craig Ringer**, works, finally works! 
You are my new idool now!

The steps are:

1. open the cmd
2. SET PGCLIENTENCODING=utf-8
3. chcp 65001
4. psql -h 192.168.114.12 -U postgres

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Thanks a lot **Craig Ringer**, works, finally works! You are my new idool now!

The steps are:

1. open the cmd
2. `SET PGCLIENTENCODING=utf-8`
3. `chcp 65001`
4. `psql -h your.ip.addr.ess -U postgres`

Comment: I recently came across a related issue and this has helped me to troubleshoot through it a bit. I just wanted to make a little note to it: server and client encoding do matter and I could only successfully `psql` to my remote server when my `PGCLIENTENCODING` was set to `iso8859-1` and I had run `chcp 1252`. I assume this was because I have my server encoding set to latin1 (a.k.a. iso8859-1). So: always mind about encodings!

Comment: Hi, Feillen, yes, and more. In this days I have to migrate some scripts from 2008 to 2012.
And the enconding problems came back, some scripts that works fine on 2008 need change the enconding or something like that.

Comment: What does line 4 do? I think get 1,2,3. But I am not sure about 4!!

Comment: Hi DT, yes, works on Win10 ( my test: https://pasteboard.co/HZ1uvgy.png )

Comment: Just want to add a remark I've just figured out. Never use PowerShell. Encoding the dump works like a charm on the standard shell but not at all with PowerShell. The file keeps encoded with UTF-16 in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 / Windows server 2016 or later:

- Open `Windows Control Panel`
- Select `Region (and Language)`
- Click  `Change system locale`
- `Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support`
- Click OK

or

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage]
"ACP"="65001"
"OEMCP"="65001"
"MACCP"="65001"
```

The PowerShell console and CMD will display Cyrillic correctly

Comment: legend this works like a treat

Answer (score 1):

As an option, try enter this command in psql :

```
postgres=# \! chcp 65001
```

65001 is equals UTF-8
1251 = WIN 1251