# UTF-8 output is no longer working for psql

Tags: windows, postgresql, utf-8, psql

Being aware of the general principles of the PostgreSQL encoding system and Windows code pages and having used it for quite a while, I no longer get valid UTF-8 output from psql and I can't figure out why.

I'm aware of the stackoverflow post [PostgreSQL: encoding problems on Windows when using psql command line utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952893/postgresql-encoding-problems-on-windows-when-using-psql-command-line-utility) and I've already double-checked that the solution presented there doesn't solve my issue - please see below.

Everything is fine as long as I stick with my (German) default windows codepage/encoding (1252/WIN1252) but as soon as I switch to UTF-8 (65001/UTF8) I get garbage characters displayed in the console window.

Please have a look at the following commands that I tried.
I'm not only interested in tips about what I'm possibly doing wrong but also in your results of executing the same commands on your system as I'm currently not sure if there is something broken on my system.

Starting a console window with `cmd /u`

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.476]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.1

C:\WINDOWS\system32>psql -c "SELECT version()"
                          version
------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
(1 Zeile)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>chcp
Aktive Codepage: 1252.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>psql -c "SHOW SERVER_ENCODING"
 server_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 Zeile)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>psql -c "SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING"
 client_encoding
-----------------
 WIN1252
(1 Zeile)

psql -c "CREATE TABLE demo(demo text)"
CREATE TABLE

C:\WINDOWS\system32>psql -c "INSERT INTO demo VALUES('ÄÖÜäöüß')"
INSERT 0 1

C:\WINDOWS\system32>psql -c "SELECT * FROM demo"
  demo
---------
 ÄÖÜäöüß
(1 Zeile)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>chcp 65001
Aktive Codepage: 65001.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>SET PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF8

C:\WINDOWS\system32>psql -c "SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING"
 client_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 Zeile)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>psql -c "SELECT * FROM demo"
  demo
---------
 Ã„Ã–ÃœÃ¤Ã¶Ã¼ÃŸ
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: Do you know when it stopped working?  was it upon upgrading from PostgreSQL 11 to 12, or was there some other identifiable change?

Comment: No, not really. I'm mostly working on WIN1252 and I rarely have to switch to UTF8. 12.0 had the same problem on this machine.

Comment: As I remember. `psql` implicitly translate server encoded text to the client where it executed and vice versa. Thus it should to work "out of the box" regardless to server/client encoding. I suppose that the `psql` "know" that your OS have `win1252` encoding and sends strings correctly, but when you change the win console encoding using `chcp` then it begun to display received strings in the incorrect way. In short: problem in the `cmd` not in the `psql` (PS: using *nix on both sides could to make your life much easier, good luck)