# Wrong characters in columns after executing SQL file from psql.exe

Tags: windows, postgresql, character-encoding, psql

I have a SQL script which populates a User table with names. I use Windows 10.

After I execute the SQL script through the command below I get wrong characters for the names if they include *`å`*, *`ä`* or *`ö`* (might be more).

```
psql.exe -h localhost -U postgres -d my_database -f C:\populate_users.sql
```

As an example, user `Peter Jönsson` becomes `Peter JÃ¶nsson`

Before I ran the command above, I also ran `chcp 1252`

If I run the SQL script from e.g. pgAdmin or Azure Data Studio, everything looks right. So the culprit seems to be psql.

Is there any additional setting I have to configure in order for this to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL: encoding problems on Windows when using psql command line utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952893/postgresql-encoding-problems-on-windows-when-using-psql-command-line-utility)

Comment: No, it doesnt. psql still write `JÃ¶nsson` to the column. It seems psql lacks some information about my system/OS? But how can it be that this works from the other clients ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistakenly set your client encoding to `WIN1252` when you imported an UTF-8 encoded file.

Run the following on your command line before starting `psql`:

```
chcp 1252
set PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF8
```

If you want to view the data with `psql`, you will have to reset the client encoding to `WIN1252`.

Comment: This worked, but only if I ran the command from cmd.exe. When I run it from powershell.exe I still get the wrong characters. Not sure if it's related but do you have any idea as to why?

Comment: Perhaps Powershell has a different way of setting environment variables?

Comment: From the docs, _If the environment variable PGCLIENTENCODING is defined in the client's environment, that client encoding is automatically selected when a connection to the server is made._. I do not have this environment variable set, still it works in e.g. Azure Data Studio. Can I assume Azure Data Studio does something more in regards to setting up the client encoding for me compared to psql then?

Comment: Yes, you can. That application knows what encoding is uses internally, so it can set `client_encoding` to the right value. `psql` can only guess from your locale settings, and in the case of Windows, I don't know if it can do that reliably. So you have to tell it what encoding to use.