# PSQL COPY statement error says character is encoded WIN1252 despite file seeming to be encoded UTF-8

Tags: python, postgresql, encoding

I am trying to copy a CSV I created in Python to a PSQL database using a copy statement and am receiving the error `PostgreSQL: character with byte sequence 0xc2 0x81 in encoding “UTF8” has no equivalent in encoding “WIN1252”`.

The original file was UTF-8, and I'm fairly certain the file I created and am trying to copy is encoded with UTF-8. I believe I added the correct params in my Python code:

```
def process_csvs():
    with open('movie_file.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as movie_file:
        movie_writer = csv.writer(movie_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
        with open('movie_basics.tsv', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter="\t")
            for row in csv_reader:
                ...
```

When I open the output file in notepad, it says the encoding is UTF-8.

My COPY statement is as follows:

```
COPY movies(movie_id, title, year, runningtime) FROM 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\movie_file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER NULL AS 'Nul
l';
```

I believe the character that is currently giving me trouble is is the accented A in: `tt0000676,Don Álvaro o la fuerza del sino,1908,Null`

Anybody know how it could be encoded WIN1252 with my configuration and any way to fix it? Thanks!

EDIT:

I recreated the database with:

```
CREATE DATABASE "scratch"
  WITH TEMPLATE template0
  ENCODING 'UTF8'
  LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
  LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

As far as I can see, everything involved is encoded in UTF-8 outside of perhaps the command line, which I believe defaults to WIN1252. I am pretty new to all of this. And I did attempt to write the file with WIN1252 encoding in my Python script, but the original data is encoded UTF-8, and the script threw errors attempting to make the conversion.

Comment: I'm going to say the issue is on the database encoding end. What version of Postgres, What OS and version are you running it on?  In `psql` what do `show lc_collate;` and `show lc_ctype;` return? Add information as update to question.

Comment: I spent a couple hours working on it this morning and just got the import to work. However, it appears what you mentioned here is important if I want to make any queries. Both lc_collate and lc_ctype are WIN1252, which appears to be the cause of my now getting the same error but with an issue converting the UTF-8 back into 1252. I had seen some things about setting the locale upon creation of the database and will look into it now. Thank you!

Comment: The simpler method for now would seem to be to get the CSV file in WIN1252.

Comment: I did change the locale stuff to UTF-8 and it is giving me the same error when I try to make a query. I can't get the original data encoded as WIN1252, and I can't seem to find a way to convert it to WIN1252 with my Python script. As it stands, I have my data in the database, and I believe my issue lies with trying to make queries from the command line, which I don't think I need to do. I think I'll leave it here. Thanks for sticking with me on the one.

Comment: Missed the deadline on editing my last comment. Clarified that I couldn't successfully convert some characters in Python and said that I am going to leave the question open, as the current solution came from pgAdmin and not getting the import from the COPY command to work.

Comment: Alright now I am thoroughly confused. Can you upgrade your question to provide a complete description of the work flow you are using? Also where in that flow the error is occurring? Also when did pgAdmin come into this?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I had turned pgAdmin when I felt I'd hit a wall using the COPY command to make the import and posted that line of exploration on a different forum. I got mixed up with what is where. Although I did successfully populate the database with the import/export tool in pgAdmin, I am still curious as to why the COPY command would not work as I outlined above. I did try recreating the database with the `locale` variables to be set to UTF-8, and that did not help. As far as I know, everything involved is UTF-8, and yet I get an error that a byte is coming in as WIN1252.

Comment: So what client are you running the `COPY` command in?

Comment: I generally use Bash, but I tried it in Command Prompt with the same result.

Comment: Where are you getting BASH in Windows? You might want to look at the answer in the SO [post](You might want to look at this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952893/postgresql-encoding-problems-on-windows-when-using-psql-command-line-utility)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235601/discussion-between-stephen-carroll-and-adrian-klaver).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Adrian Klaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver) for sticking with me and ultimately pointing me to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952893/postgresql-encoding-problems-on-windows-when-using-psql-command-line-utility), which explained how to change the encoding of Postgres and the active code page of the terminal within CMD. The COPY statement worked fine after that.

The steps outlined in the post are:

1. open cmd
2. `SET PGCLIENTENCODING=utf-8`
3. `chcp 65001`
4. Log into Postgres

For any who are coming into this clueless about encoding, CP65001 (Code Page 65001) is Windows's way of specifying UTF-8 encoding. `SET PGCLIENTENCODING=utf-8` changes the encoding of the client in Postgres to be UTF-8, and then `chcp 65001` changes the active code page of the console to match it.