# Heroku & Django - Change client encoding from WIN1252 to UTF8

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

So I have my Django application deployed on a Heroku server and when I try to query for `Post` I get this.

How I query

```
// Command to get into postgres
heroku pg:psql
// Query
SELECT * FROM posts;
```

What I get back

```
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xf0 0x9f 0x98 0x84 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

I'm decently sure what is happening is that someone created a post where the `body` has an emoji in it. I'm using Postgresql it supports `UTF8` for storing. So I'm not really sure why this is happening because Django should default to `UTF8`, because it's running postgres and then I ran this command to check the server encoding.

```
>>>heroku pg:psql -c "show server_encoding"
--> Connecting to postgresql-round-92478
 server_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

So I'm not sure which part of the client server is in `WIN1252` and needs to be converted to `UTF8`.

**How do I change client encoding from `WIN1252` to `UTF8`?**

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator")
    body = models.CharField(max_length=POST_MAX_LEN, validators=[MinLengthValidator(POST_MIN_LEN)])
```

Setup:

- Postgresql
- Django 3.2.9
- Deployed on Heroku

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952893/postgresql-encoding-problems-on-windows-when-using-psql-command-line-utility answer your question?

Comment: i think your problem is not from postgres but from the cmdline. your command line cannot show the characters gotten from postgres. To confirm this, try accessing your database from your dashboard and run this sql query. you shouldn't encounter this error.

Comment: @Chymdy what's "dashboard?" I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: Your heroku dashboard i mean.

Comment: @Chymdy yea good advice let me take a look