# psql 9.6 returns broken characters while using Windows CMD

Tags: postgresql, powershell, psql

I have installed PostgreSQL 9.6.2 on a 64-bit Windows 10 machine.

I have executed psql.exe.

As you see the below picture,

[image: psql.exe]

it shows broken characters. PowerShell also shows the same result.

How can I solve this broken character problem?

-Best Regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952893/postgresql-encoding-problems-on-windows-when-using-psql-command-line-utility and https://stackoverflow.com/q/19290750/478656  any use ?

Comment: My bads. Thanks for helping me @TessellatingHeckler. The first link helped me by typing chcp 437 at the CMD, instead of 65001.